# How to find one element of residue field as a vector over base field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I define a Function field in $y$ defined by $y^2 + y + \frac{x^2 + 1}{x}$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Its rational places are

> [Place $(\frac{ 1}{x}, \frac{ 1}{x} y)$, Place $(x, x y)$, Place $(x + 1, x y)$, Place $(x + 1, x y + 1)$]

and degree two places are

> [Place $(x^2 + x + 1, x y + 1)$, Place $(x^2 + x + 1, x y + x + 1)$]

If I take divisor $G=$ Place $(x^2 + x + 1, x y + x + 1)$, basis of corresponding Riemann Roch space is $[1, (\frac{xy}{(x^2 + x + 1))} + \frac{1}{x^2 + x + 1})]$.

What is the value of $\frac{xy}{(x^2 + x + 1) } + \frac{1}{x^2 + x + 1}+$ Place $(x^2 + x + 1, x y + 1)$ ?

It is an element of residue field which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$. Since $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ is isomorphic 
to $\mathbb{F}^2_{2}$ as a vector space, I want value in $\mathbb{F}^2_{2}$. What is the working rule here in general.